# I'm having trouble getting circle handles to play nice with nouislider

Tags: css, nouislider

I'm using these styles:

```
/** noUISlider overrides */
.noUi-horizontal
  height: 20px

.noUi-target
  background: #e0e0e0
  border-radius: 20px
  border: 0
  box-shadow: none

.noUi-connect
  background: #21528d
  margin: 0 10px

.noUi-handle
  border-radius: 10px
  border: 2px solid #21528d
  box-shadow: none
  width: 20px !important
  height: 20px !important
  left: 0px !important
  top: 0px !important

.noUi-handle-upper
  left: -20px !important

.noUi-handle:after
  display: none

.noUi-handle:before
  width: 8px
  height: 8px
  border-radius: 10px
  top: 4px
  left: 4px
  background: #c3c3c3
```

Which results in this slider:

[image: Slider screenshot 1]

which is exactly what I want. The problem comes in when I slide the upper handle all the way to 0:

[image: Slider screenshot 2]

The upper bound anchors on the right side and the lower bound anchors on the left side....which means the upper bound actually slides past the lower bound and resides to the left of it in the last screenshot.

It must be a simple style adjustment, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it and I'm hoping someone has already solved this problem and can share the answer.